# How do I call function in a separate thread in Julia 0.5-dev?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I know, that native threads support in Julia is still incomplete, but I want to live on the bleeding edge. I've built master branch with `JULIA_THREADS=1`, and automatic multithreading with `@threads` works fine.

What I want is just to call my own function in a separate native thread. AFAIK `jl_threading_run` used by `@threads` doesn't suit me because it will call my function in several threads simultaneously. Of course, I can try to workaround this behaviour by checking thread number and doing work only in one of them. But I'm sure that more straight way must exist. I've skimmed through C implementation of multithreading support, but my knowledge of C and Julia internals is not enough to figure out how to complete my task.

Comment: I am interested in this as well. [I opened an issue here on the JuliaLang Github repo](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17933)

Comment: I spent a while digging around in the internals, so see if I could make this work using `jl_threading_run`. Where you immediately terminate in nontargetted threads. And fire it off using a `async`, but always yield, before terminating in thread-id 1. But I couldn't quiet get it to work.
I think to do what I wanted to do you actually need to always be inside a eternally looping `jl_threading_run` (even for your "main" thread), and have each thread polling/waiting for work -- like setting up a work stealing archetecture.

Comment: Another problem is that even if we would manage to run function in a separate thread, all I/O tasks, timers, REPL commands, etc are multiplexed onto a single OS thread via an event loop. At the moment Julia is not designed for SMP. Perhaps we should stick with running parallel processes and doing message passing for most tasks and just not use Julia for cases like mine was: sound synth server, threads where required for I/O parallelisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all changed with Julia 1.3, [this article](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/07/multithreading) explains the new multithreading model of julia